# Div onblur event called when clicking checkbox inside div

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I have a popup div and want to hide it when users click outside of the div. Inside the div, I have a checkbox...

Problem is, the div's onblur event gets fired when trying to click on the checkbox. I put cancelEventBubble code on the onclick of the checkbox but the onblur fires before the checkbox onclick event...

any ideas or suggestions? This seems so simple to do but is not quite that simple...

Regards,
Albert

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
.popup
{
    display: none;
    position: relative;    
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

.lookupButton
{
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.lookup
{
    border: solid 1px green;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var popupVisible = false;

function cancelEventBubble(e) {
     if (!e) var e = window.event;
     e.cancelBubble = true;
     if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}

function showPopup(obj)
{
    if (!popupVisible)
    {
        popupVisible = true;
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("popup").focus();
    }
    else
    {
        popupVisible = false;
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "";
    }
}

function hidePopup()
{
    popupVisible = false;
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "";
}

function setTextValue(obj)
{
    var combo = document.getElementById("cbo1");
    if (combo.value.indexOf(obj.value) == -1)
    {
        combo.value += obj.value + "; ";
    }
    else
    {
        combo.value = combo.value.replace(obj.value + "; ", "");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td>
    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="cbo1" id="cbo1" />
</td><td>
    <div class="lookupButton" onclick="showPopup(this);"></div>
</td></tr></table>

<div id="popup" class="popup" onblur="hidePopup()">
    <input id="chk0" type="checkbox" onclick="cancelEventBubble(event); setTextValue(this);" value="John" />John<br />
    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" onclick="cancelEventBubble(event); setTextValue(this);" value="Jack" />Jack<br />
    <input id="chk2" type="checkbox" onclick="cancelEventBubble(event); setTextValue(this);" value="James" />James<br />
    <input id="chk3" type="checkbox" onclick="cancelEventBubble(event); setTextValue(this);" value="Richard" />Richard<br />
    <input id="chk4" type="checkbox" onclick="cancelEventBubble(event); setTextValue(this);" value="Tim" />Tim<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't that simple. There's one way to do it, using JQuery framework, if you care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern browsers the [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onblur) event doesn't fires with `div` elements, a crossbrowser approach that can also deal with the issues of IE could be to use [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/), binding a click event handler to the document, and hide the popup when the clicked element is not a checkbox or the `lookupButton`, for example:

```
document.onclick = function (e) { 
  e = e || window.event; 
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement; 

  if (element.tagName != "INPUT" && element.type != "checkbox" &&
      element.className != "lookupButton") { 
    hidePopup(); 
  } 
};
```

Check the above example with the rest of your code [here](http://jsbin.com/izefu).

Comment: Thanks, that is a good approach, I will play with it a little.

-Albert

Answer (score 0):

Try going about it the other way.  Use a three-layered approach where the bottom layer is the normal page, the top layer is your popup div, and the middle layer is a transparent, full-screen catch-all div that has an `onfocus` event that closes your popup (rather than using `onblur`).

If you provide some code, it'll be easier to help with your approach.